# How to spin up all nodes in my EMR cluster before running my spark job

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I have an EMR cluster that can scale up to a maximum of 10 `SPOT` nodes. When not being used it defaults to 1 `CORE` node (and 1 `MASTER`) to save costs obviously. So in total it can scale up to a maximum of 11 nodes `1 CORE + 10 SPOT`.
When I run my spark job it takes a while to spin up the 10 `SPOT` nodes and my job ends up taking about 4hrs to complete.
I tried waiting until all the nodes were spun up, then canceled my job and immediately restarted it so that it can start using the max resources immediately, and my job took only around 3hrs to complete.

I have 2 questions:

**1.** Is there a way to make YARN spin up all the necessary resources before starting my job? I already specify the spark-submit parameters such as `num-executors`, `executor-memory`, `executor-cores` etc. during job submit.

**2.** I havent done the cost analysis yet, but is it even worthwhile to do number 1 mentioned above? Does AWS charge for spin up time, even when a job is not being run?

Would love to know your insights and suggestions.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using AWS managed scaling for this. If you can switch to custom scaling you can set more aggressive scaling rules, you can also set the numbers of nodes to scale up by on each upscale and downscale, this will help you converge faster to the required number of nodes.

The only downside to custom scaling is that it will take 5 minutes to trigger.

Comment: Ah I see. Alas, the scaling is managed by the IT department in my company. I'll have to schmooze them into setting little aggressive scaling levels for my cluster. Time to get a case of beer :P 
Thank you for the info!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to make YARN spin up all the necessary resources before
> starting my job?

I **do not know** how to achieve this. But, In my opinion, **this is not worth** doing it. Spark is intelligent enough to do this for us.

It knows how to distribute the task when more instances come up or go away in the cluster. There is a certain spark configuration which you should be aware of to achieve this.

You should set this to **true** `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled`. There are some other relevant configurations that you can change or leave it as it is.

For more detail refer to this documentation [spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/configuration.html#dynamic-allocation)

Please see the documentation as per your spark version. This link is for the spark version `2.4.0`

> Does AWS charge for spin up time, even when a job is not being run?

You get charged **for every second of the instance that you use**, with a one-minute minimum. It is not important whether your job is being run or not. **Even If they are idle in the cluster, you will have to pay for it.**

Refer to these link for more detail:

[EMR FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/emr/faqs/)

[EMR PRICING](https://aws.amazon.com/emr/pricing/)

Hope this gives you some idea about the EMR pricing and certain spark configuration related to the dynamic allocation.

Comment: I am aware of the `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled`. Unfortunately, I cant use it since my job uses a large dataset and I had to calculate the spark parameters to optmize the job timing.
However when the job starts and has one node to work with, I get failed tasks with `isDataPresent: false` and `Fetchfailed` errors. When enough nodes are spun up, it retries a second time (due to the large no o failed tasks) and then is able to succeed quite fast.